# Ignoring KeyError while writing to file with dask.to_csv

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, keyerror

I have a dataframe, which is not loaded into memory (and it should stay like that).
At some point in the script I apply a conversion with a dictionary to one of the dataframe columns in the following manner:

```
df['identifier'] = df.identifier.map(lambda identifier: alias_dict[str(identifier)],
                                                               meta=('identifier', str))
```

KeyError exceptions are not found out on this stage but just when I use `to_csv` so I try to handle them

```
try:
   dd.to_csv(intersection_df, output, header=None, index=None, single_file=True, sep='\t')
except KeyError as err:
   print(f'Unmatched key {err.args[0]}')
```

In case I encounter a KeyError, the writing to the file is stopped - is there a way to make the writing continue even if I get an exception at that stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do, if you want to skip or remediate the failing lines but keep writing, is to put your try/except into the mapping function

```
def alias(identifier):
    try:
        return alias_dict[str(identifier)]
    except KeyError:
        return identifier

df['identifier'] = df.identifier.map(alias, meta=('identifier', str))
```

In this case, failures are passed through unchanged. You could turn them into None and filter them out in a second step, or the two steps could be combined with `map_partitions`.

Comment: Is there a way to pass `df` as an argument to `alias` as well?

Comment: Not in this formulation, no. Row-wise operations are very different from ones that need the whole data.